# Match the 3rd occurence of the text between square brackets using regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract the 3rd occurence of the text between square brackets using regex. My string is something like following.

```
[TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-11 11:07:46,919]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Halting JVM {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}]
```

How can I use regex to extract the date and time, which is inside the 3rd square bracket?

I want the result to be,

2016-03-11 11:07:46,919

Comment: can't you just use regex to find the pattern for dates rather than the 3rd brackets?

Comment: That would be better. But how? I'm not familiar with regex :(

Comment: Could you provide us with a result how you want the final result to looks like in the question please

Thank you in advance

Comment: @DanielElmnas Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are very many ways to handle this,

Here is a very fast solution if the format is always as you showed us above:

Regex: 
`(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[ ]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})`


Result:

`2016-03-11 11:07:46,919`

Regards

Daniel